# Glympse REST API - expired tickets

Tags: glympse

I have two questions on the Glympse API:

1. I am sharing my location by (initially creating a ticket,) uploading location data (/v2/tickets/ticketID/append_location) and appending data (/v2/tickets/ticketID/append_data). If there is already a ticket existing, I am just uploading more recent data (append_location + append_data) and update the ticket (/v2/tickets/ticketID/update?duration=ticketDuration). **Now, once the ticket has expired how can I make it active again?** Currently I am creating a new ticket which makes the "same user" (but with different ticket) appear again in the Glympse mobile app.
2. In a group, I can see expired users for a very long time. Once they do not share their location anymore, it takes one or two days until they are removed from the group. How can I remove them instantly once their ticket has become expired?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Once a ticket is expired it cannot be reactivated. Small snippet from the Glympse programming guide: https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/client-sdk/guides/common/programming-guide

> Tickets can only transition into GC::TICKET_EXPIRED state once. A ticket is considered immutable after it transitions into the expired state. It leaves the expired state only if being deleted explicitly. This is the only operation that is allowed for expired tickets.

2. A group member can remove themselves immediately from a group by sending a POST groups/[group_id]/leave

Otherwise, as you noticed the member's ticket information will remain in the group for 48 hours following their ticket's expiration. Group members cannot remove another member from a group.

Comment: How is the smartphone app handling it, when I share a location after my last ticket has expired? In the app my name&location is only shown once in the group, the expired ones are not visible anymore.
I wonder how I can do the same?

Comment: When querying for group events, a response that contains a new invite code will also have the user_id for the group member that is sharing to the group. You can keep track of these user_ids and anytime a new invite event is received, check against your list of user_ids to see if this invite replaces an existing one. The client sdk used by the app does this in the GroupManager & Group classes.

Comment: I dont quite understand your answer. Could you share in which order which API functions need to be called?

Like i described in my question, I am using those functions one after another:
 a) no ticket available yet (initial share):
  - /v2/users/self/create_ticket
  - /v2/tickets/append_location
  - /v2/tickets/ticketID/append_data
  - /v2/tickets/ticketID/create_invite
 b) ticket is already available (follow up shares):
  - /v2/tickets/append_location
  - /v2/tickets/ticketID/append_data
c) existing ticket expired (see next comment)

Comment: c) existing ticket expired
  - start with a) **and delete expired ticket**

How is it supposed to be done right? The user is still visible in the group even though his ticket got deleted
According to [link](https://developer.glympse.com/docs/core/client-sdk/guides/common/groups#dealing-with-groups) "However, it is possible to leave a group (stop being a group member) almost instantly by deleting the most recently ticket sent to it (using ITicket::deleteTicket())"

Comment: It sounds like you are making the api calls in the correct order. The user is still in the group for a short time after their ticket is deleted but since their ticket is deleted, the location information in their ticket will no longer be available. Testing in the app shows this same behavior.

Comment: I think I got it now, there was a bug in my code, I did not use the respective access token to delete the ticket.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

For others who are interested: The answer to my question is very simple. If a ticket for a user has expired, this very user needs to delete his ticket "/v2/tickets/ticketID/delete?oauth_token=oauth". With the deletion of the ticket, the expired position will vanish immediately.